# Rails helper modules in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a controller, I want to create a helper for this controller that I can use without including it. I tried creating a helper with the same name as the controller like so

```
class Cars::EnginesController < ApplicationController
  def start_engine
    check_fuel
  end
end
```

and the helper that i created was

```
module Cars::EnginesHelper
  def check_fuel
    logger.debug("cheking fuel")
  end
end
```

and the error that i got was

```
undefined local variable or method `check_fuel' for #<Cars::EnginesController:0x1160e8c80>
```

is there any conventions that i am missing out?

Comment: Did you generate the files using the `rails generate controller` command? If not, are you sure the file structure matches Rails conventions?

Comment: yes, the controller was generated using "rails generate" command, but i manually added the helper file. I have followed the directory structure perfectly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to use helper methods in controller, you can treat your helper as regular Ruby module (which it is, honestly) and use `include`:

```
class Cars::EnginesController < ApplicationController
  include Cars::EnginesHelper
  # ...
end
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't address why the module is not being automatically included as it should. If the directory structure is the issue, wouldn't this still fail as Rails fails to successfully lookup the constant?

Comment: I don't see the problem you're addressing here Paul, with Mareks' answer it extends the controller methods with those defined in the EnginesHelper lib. Since rails 3 something the config doesn't automaticly load the /lib directory by default.

Comment: @PaulSimpson you gave answer to yourself: helpers don't get automatically included in controllers.

Comment: @ all thanks for the answers, but i'm working on rails 2.3. According to the rails guide on page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html, it says "In previous versions of Rails the controller will include a helper whose name matches that of the controller, e.g., MyController will automatically include MyHelper" which is not happening. Can somebody highlight on that. 

I have also tried including as @MarekLipka suggested and it works fine when i do that. But i'm still puzzled over the statement from rails guide

Comment: @Vignesh yes, but it's all about including these helpers in views. So yes, helpers are automatically included in views, not in controllers.

Comment: @MarekLipka, thanks. But, it still doesn't explain the statement that i posted from rails guide site.

Comment: @Vignesh it does. Please read this statement carefully. This is all about including helpers in views.

Comment: @MarekLipka Ha! That's what I get for reading SO before coffee :) You're completely right and I was conflating controllers and the view context. Thanks for setting the record straight! (and h/t to dennis as well!).